# creating new ArrayList with elements from another one

Tags: java, arraylist, ranking

I'm writing the code of my first Java game right now and I have a problem with `ArrayList`. I have one, with elements like nicknames and scores, to be specific I create it from the text file(code below):

```
static ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ranking));
        String line = br.readLine();
        results.add(line);

while(line != null) {
    line = br.readLine();
    results.add(line);
}

br.close();
```

So the file looks like this:

```
nick1
score1
nick2
score2
...
```

I would like to make a ranking with top 10 best results, my idea is to make the class with the fields nick and score and somehow assign that fields to appriopriate ones from the ArrayList. Maybe I can do this like this:(?)

```
for(int i = 0;i<results.size();i=i+2){
    nick = results.get(i);
}

for(int i = 1;i<results.size();i=i+2){
    score = results.get(i);
}
```

Then I would create a new `ArrayList`, which would be in the type of that new class. But my problem is that I don't exactly know how I can connect values from 'old' `ArrayList` with the paramaters of future type of new `ArrayList`. The new one should be like:

```
static ArrayList<Ranking> resultsAfterModification = new ArrayList<Ranking>();
Ranking rank = new Ranking(nick, score);
```

Then I can easily compare players' scores and make a solid ranking.

Comment: why you are using ArrayList?Use HashMap instead of it,it like key value pair e.g nickname1=score1,nickname2=score2.so you do any operation on it.sorting,adding,deleting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class `Player` that contains the name and score of each player. The `Player` class should implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface which is Java's way of figuring out the logical order of elements in a collection:

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player>
{
    private String _name;
    private double _score;

    public Player(String name, double score)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._score = score;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this._name;
    }

    public double getScore()
    {
        return this._score;
    }

    // Since you probably want to sort the players in
    // descending order, I'm comparing otherScore to this._score.
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Player otherScore) 
    {
        return Double.compare(otherScore._score, this._score);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: " + this._name + ", Score: " + Double.toString(this._score);
    }
}
```

Once you've created the `Player` class, you can read both name and score in one go and use the [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) utility class to sort the `Player` list. Last but not least, you could grab the top ten by using the `subList` method: (this assumes that the file will have a score for each name and the file will be in the format you specified above)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Player> results = new ArrayList<Player>();
    BufferedReader br;
    try 
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            String name = line;
            double score = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            results.add(new Player(name, score));
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Sort using the java.util.Collections utility class
    // Sorting will modify your original list so make a copy
    // if you need to keep it as is.
    Collections.sort(results);
    // Top 10
    List<Player> top10 = results.subList(0, 10);
}
```

Comment: In `List.subList()` method, the second parameter : `toIndex` is exclusive. So to have the top 10, you should write `results.subList(0, 10)` else it is Top 9 :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I was looking for. Now how can I display that list into JLabel? This isn't fix unfortunately:
JLabel PlayersRanking = new JLabel();
for(Player p : top10) {
   PlayersRanking.setText(String.valueOf(p));
         }

Comment: @JeffTheKiller  I'm not super familiar with swing. 99% of the work I've done and do in Java is either back-end or numerical stuff. I glanced at this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_jlabel.htm and it looks like it's a place to start. You can always post another question should you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should program by Interface (`List` instead of `ArrayList` in declared type) here because you don't use methods specific to `ArrayList`.

```
List<Ranking> resultsAfterModification = new ArrayList<Ranking>();
```

2)

> Then I would create a new ArrayList, which would be in the type of
>   that new class. But my problem is that I don't exactly know how I can
>   connect values from 'old' ArrayList with the paramaters of future type
>   of new ArrayList.

To do it, you don't need many changes.
Your idea a is little too complex because finally you perform two mappings : one where you store from read line to `List` of `String` and another one where you store from `List` of `String` to `List` of `Ranking` .
You can direct map read line  to `List` of `Ranking`.

```
   List<Ranking> rankings = new ArrayList<Ranking>();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ranking));

   String nick = null;
   while ( (nick = br.readLine()) != null){
           String score = br.readLine();
           rankings.add(new Ranking(nick, score));
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save array in file :

1 use, FileInputStram and FileOuputStream to write and read array object to file.

2 use Gson library to save and load array as json

3 write as normal  textfile like below: 
Player 1
Score 1
Player 2
Score 2 
....

```
ArrayList<Player> list=new ArrayList();
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("filepath.txt"));
While(sc.hasNextLine()){
  Player p=new Player();
  p.name=sc.nextLine();
  If(sc.hasNextFloat()){
     p.score=sc.nextFloat();
     list.add(p);
  }
}
Arrays.sort(list,...);
```

And can sort array by Arrays.sort()

Answer (score 0):

So your `Ranking` class might look like

```
public class Ranking {
    public String nick;
    public int score;
}
```

I think the `nick` and `score` are two `ArrayList` containing nicks and scores respectively.

So to create a common `ArrayList`, if the sizes of `nick` and `score` are the same, you might do something like this.

```
static ArrayList<Ranking> resultsAfterModification = new ArrayList<Ranking>();
for(int i = 0; i < nick.size(); i++) {
    Ranking rank = new Ranking(nick.get(i), score.get(i));
    resultsAfterModification.add(rank);
}
```

Now you need to write your own comparator to sort the values inside `resultsAfterModification`

```
Collections.sort(resultsAfterModification, new Comparator<Ranking>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Ranking r1, Ranking r2) {
        if (r1.score > r2.score)
            return 1;
        if (r1.score < r2.score)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: In compare you can just return r1.score-r2.score;